# Windows Server 2012 R2 kernel threads increase until the system hang

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, kernel, threads, process-explorer

I have a small problem with my Windows Server 2012 R2. At the moment the problem is that the threads from "NT Kernel & System" increase every second until they reach 16k, and then the server becomes very slow or hangs. When I try to debug the process with Process Explorer:

[image: Process Explorer Screen Shot]

Here you can see that something spawned a new thread and wait. I've tried to stop all my services but i can't find a solution. Have any of you had the same problem in the past?

Comment: Can you right-click on the process and see the full path?

Comment: No if i make a double-click i get the info "Unable to access thread" and right-click has no function.

Comment: Are you running Process Explorer as an elevated process? You may be logged in with an administrator account, but please be sure to still right-click on Process Explorer and select "Run as administrator." That should get you access to the process and thread info.

Comment: Yes it's running as Administrator but the same. I'm loggedin as Domain Admin so a should have enough rights but i've testet it and no chance...

Comment: Just to be clear, you still need to "Run as administrator" even when you are logged in as a Domain Administrator. (You can thank UAC for that.)

Comment: Yes ;) but i have no access...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59142/discussion-between-stony-and-sturdyerde).

Comment: So, what was the answer here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This explains the issue. Combination of KB4019215  and bad iSCSI connections.

https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/6cum10/headsup_2012_r2_servers_with_iscsi/

Comment: That fix isn't installed on my system. And i don't use iSCSI anymore. I have uninstalled all iSCSI packages. So i don't thing that this is the problem.

Comment: I've checked iSCSI again. The service was not running but the old connection was active after restart the service. Now i've deleted all connections and i think it looked good now.